# How can I isolate F in the formula for the Odds Ratio Skill Score?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In an area I work in (weather forecasting) there is a measure of skill called the Odds Ratio Skill Score (ORSS).

Let's say we're talking about tornados. The ORSS takes in:

1. the proportion of times you say "yes there's a tornado" then there really is one. That's $H$, the hit rate.
2. The proportion of times you say "yes there's a tornado" then there isn't really one. That's $F$, the false alarm rate.

The formula is as follows:

$ORSS = \frac{H - F}{H+F-2HF}$

I need to design a function that takes in ORSS value (let's say 0.6), and then calculates the F rate that is required to create that ORSS for particular values of H.

So, for example, if the desired ORSS is 0.6 then the function would work out that for a H of 0.01 we need a F of 0.02703, for an H of 0.02 we need an F of 0.05882, and so on.

How should I do that? I felt like I needed to isolate F on one side of the equation. However, I wasn't sure how to rearrange the terms so that I could do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

multiplying by the denominator we obtain
$$ORSS(H+F-2HF)=H-F$$
expanding we get
$$ORSS\cdot H+F(1-2H)ORSS+F=H$$
now we isolating $F$:
$$F\left((1-2H)ORSS+1\right)=H-ORSS\cdot H$$
thus we get
$$F=\frac{H(1-ORSS)}{(1-2H)ORSS+1}$$

Comment: i hope i have interpreted right your formula